# How to avoid "Objects have changed outside of Terraform"?

Tags: terraform

Recently upgraded my Terraform project to AWS provider 3.74.0 and TF 1.1.4 (from much older versions).

I'm suddenly getting this autoscaling schedule reporting external changes:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "api-svc-tst-down-schedule" {
  scheduled_action_name = "api-svc-tst-down-schedule"
  min_size              = 0
  max_size              = 1
  desired_capacity      = 0

  // Minute Hour DayOfMonth Month DayOfWeek
  recurrence             = "0 13 * * *" 
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.api-svc-tst-asg.name
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [start_time]
  }
}
```

The `plan` command is now reporting:

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply":

  # aws_autoscaling_schedule.api-svc-tst-down-schedule has changed
  ~ resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "api-svc-tst-down-schedule" {
        id                     = "api-svc-tst-down-schedule"
      ~ start_time             = "2022-01-31T13:00:00Z" -> "2022-02-01T13:00:00Z"
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

If I `apply` the plan, it doesn't appear that TF changes the ASG (I'm assuming it just updates its state file) and the notification goes away until the next day.

I note that the AWS console does show that the `Scheduled action` has a `Start time`, which seems to be being set by AWS.

I tried adding `start_time` to `ignored_changes` but it didn't seem to make a difference, still reported as externally changed.

Is this a known issue with Terraform (I'm not seeing anything via googling)?
How can I prevent TF from being marked as externally changed?

**Edit**: I also tried setting the `start_time` attribute as suggested in the comments.  But the detected changes warning came back the next day.

**Edit 2**: I also tried deleting and re-adding the resource via Terraform, but it still gets marked as changed the next day.

Comment: In a plan, it will always show as changed. But applying your tf with `ignore_changes` should not perform any change action.

Comment: So autoscaling-schedules will from now on show up intermittently as having been externally modified? That's going to be pleasant :(

Comment: You can try setting it yourself explicitly, rather then having AWS set it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This undesirable behavior was an intentional change introduced in Terraform [version 0.15.4](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.15/CHANGELOG.md#0154-may-19-2021).

It cannot currently be avoided. The only workaround is that all team members (and tooling) must be educated to ignore "expected drift".

Note that this "expected drift" behavior is not limited to just `aws_autoscaling_schedule` resources, or even just the AWS provider. The issue happens on many different platforms/types for any resource where the cloud vendor updates the attribute after the resource is created.

Many resources will report drift immediately after being created - often you can get rid of the report by immediately doing an `apply` or `refresh` to update the TF state and as long as AWS doesn't make changes to those attributes, you won't see the resource reported as changed again.

Other resource attributes (like `aws_autoscaling_schedule.start_time`) get updated by the cloud vendor regularly.  These types of resources will intermittently report "Objects have changed outside of Terraform", whenever you run `plan`.

There is a *locked* open issue to track: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28803.

Note that the issue is locked because Hashicorp got tired of people telling them how negatively this affects their teams.