# How to avoid empty "Objects have changed outside of Terraform"?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: even though this question is related to [How to avoid "Objects have changed outside of Terraform"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933858/how-to-avoid-objects-have-changed-outside-of-terraform) it's not exactly the same.

I can't share my exact TF configuration but the idea is I'm getting **an empty** "Objects have changed outside of Terraform" warning message?

```
$ terraform plan
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply":


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to
these changes.

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

that doesn't display any potential changes.

When I copy my current state and then compare it against the new state after running `terraform apply --auto-approve` there're no changes either:

```
diff terraform.tfstate old.tfstate                          
4c4
<   "serial": 25,
---
>   "serial": 24,
217d216
<             "data.foo.test",
219c218,219
<             "data.bar.test2"
---
>             "data.bar.test2",
>             "data.bar.test2"
```

seems the only diff is ordering of resource in TF state. Is it TF bug or something?

```
$ terraform version 
Terraform v0.15.4
```

Also found related issues on GitHub: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28776

Comment: This May happen if you used `count` instead of `for_each` or tf Code might have gotten a `set` & you assume it’s a `list`. Have you turned on debug to check why you have this `diff`?

Comment: There's no `count` / `for_each`. The set / list suggestion could be the case. What kind of log should I be looking for in traces?

Comment: I searched for set / list and didn't find anything related but I do use list / set in the code.

Comment: so I've been using `[]interface{}{map[string]interface{}{ foo: bar }}})` for both TypeSet and TypeList, shall I be more granular? @harshavmb

Comment: Switched everything to TypeSet and `[]interface{}{map[string]interface{}{ foo: bar }}}` and still getting this error

Comment: what's even more interesting, it's not consistent: shows up during 1/3 `terraform plan`

Comment: This is due to specific READ function returns in the provider resource schema. Without knowing the specific resource, you would be unable to progress unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of odd behavior can occur in response to quirks in the way particular providers handle the "refresh" step. For backward compatibility with Terraform providers written using the older SDK designed for Terraform v0.11 and earlier, the plan renderer will suppress certain differences that tend to arise due to limitations/flaws in that SDK, such as a value being `null` before refresh but `""` (empty string) after refresh.

Unfortunately if that sort of change is the *only* change then it can confuse Terraform in this way, where Terraform can see that there is a difference but then when it tries to render the difference it gets suppressed as legacy SDK noise and so there ends up being no difference to report.

This behavior was refined in later versions of Terraform, and so upgrading to the latest v1.x.y release may avoid the problem, assuming it's one of the quirks that the Terraform team already addressed.

I think the reason why you don't see any change to the *state* here could be that, since there were no changes to make in response to differences in your configuration, Terraform skipped the "apply" step and thus didn't actually commit the refreshed state. You can force Terraform to treat the refresh changes as something to be committed by creating and applying a refresh-only plan:

```
terraform apply -refresh-only
```

Assuming that the provider that's misbehaving here is consistent in how it misbehaves (that is: once it's returned a marginally different value, if it will *keep* returning that value), after applying the refresh only plan you would no longer see this message because future refreshes of the same object will not detect any such immaterial differences.

Comment: For my config, `terraform apply -refresh-only` shows 0 changes. What I did find though is this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/159 and I do have an attribute that is both Optional + Default (that's pretty much only warning log in my logs).